# Why does SELECTing sum() return null instead of 0 when there are no matching records?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, null, coalesce

This is but one of countless little details that make me frustrated all the time, forces me to memorize all kinds of special code and causes my queries to become uglier than they should have to be.

Try this query on for size:

```
SELECT sum(amount) FROM table WHERE conditions;
```

If it finds no records to `sum()` the amount of, it returns empty/null/undefined instead of 0, causing the output to be unexpectedly empty in my application, instead of the "sum" of zero. But `sum()` means "the sum", so why not just return 0?

I am aware of the solution. You "simply" do:

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(amount), 0) FROM table WHERE conditions;
```

Now it will return 0 even if there are no records. But it's ugly and it no longer feels "fun" to use. Not that databases are supposed to be a "fun game", but you know what I mean: if a query becomes too convoluted/"ugly", it no longer feels satisfying to use it, especially if you know that this will have to be repeated in all kinds of places and it's not just some obscure, one-off edge case.

What was the thought process behind making it behave like this? I have many other issues related to `null`, but I'll focus on this one thing for this question.

Comment: See also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25435/why-does-ansi-sql-define-sumno-rows-as-null

Answer (score 10):

This is specified by the SQL standard in section *4.16.4 Aggregate functions*:
:

> If no row qualifies, then the result of COUNT is 0 (zero), and the result of any other aggregate function is the null value.

Answer (score 0):

Note that it happens only if all values are `NULL` or has no values/entries at all.

You can (and should) always test what happens behind the curtains.

Example with custom values:

```
WITH test_data (a, b) as (
  SELECT * 
  FROM (VALUES 
         ('example1', 1), 
         ('example2', 2), 
         ('example3', NULL), 
         ('example3', 3), 
         (NULL, NULL), 
         (NULL, 5), 
         (NULL, 5),
         ('example4', NULL)
       ) t
)
SELECT 
  a,
  SUM(b) AS b
FROM test_data
GROUP BY 1
```

Answer (score -1):

> If it finds no records to sum() the amount of, it returns empty/null/undefined instead of 0, causing the output to be unexpectedly empty in my application, instead of the "sum" of zero. But sum() means "the sum", so why not just return 0?

Simply because:

```
NULL  !=  0
```

NULL is not any kind of *default* value, it is not any kind of *known* value.
It is the deliberate means of recording the *absence* of any, meaningful value.

The sum of NULLs is NULL.
The result of *any* aggregate function on NULLs is NULL.
The result of *any* operation *at all* on NULLs is NULL.

Here's a "fun" one:
NULL is not "equal" to anything else, not even NULL *itself*!

```
NULL is NULL    True
NULL =  NULL    False
NULL != NULL    False
```

Comment: *"The result of any aggregate function on NULLs is NULL."*: irrelevant. The sum is over an empty set of rows, there are no NULL values involved.

Comment: True, but there are no /non-NULL/ values either! ;-)

Comment: I see the joke but still. Your answer focuses on NULL, which I think is irrelevant for the question.

Comment: NULL = NULL is not False, it is NULL. Same with <>

Comment: I agree `NULL` is irrelevant here, there are no rows to evaluate at all. More the point, `COUNT(*)` *does* return `0` so it's not entirely logical. It might make more sense if [scalar aggregates did the same as vector aggregates](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/03/fun-with-aggregates.html) and returned no rows, but they always return 1 row

Answer (score -1):

From postgre 7.1 you can create custom aggregates

```sql
create or replace function sum0_iteration(state int, value int) 
returns int language sql
as 'select state + coalesce(value, 0)';

create or replace aggregate sum0(int) (
    stype = int,
    sfunc = 'sum0_iteration',
    initcond = 0
);
```

Of course, you'll have to overload this functions for different argument type, not just `int`, but user queries becomes a little better ))

```sql
select sum(1), sum0(1) where false

sum|sum0|
---+----+
   |   0|
```

Comment: ... and yes, i have no idea why standard behaviour is so ridiculous. but it's standard

Answer (score -2):

My solution for this problem is:

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(amount), 0) FROM table WHERE conditions;
```

I think it's more clearer and easier to read and understand. Nevertheless it would be a nice config setting aka NULL_SUM_TO_ZERO ...